# QProcess becomes zombie when I use dolfin::Mesh

Tags: c++, qt, mesh, qprocess

I have a code that uses Qt4 and FEniCS. Here is an example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <dolfin.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //dolfin::Mesh mesh;
    process = new QProcess();
    connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(processFinished()));
    process->start("ls");
}

void MainWindow::processFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Process finished";
}
```

It is a simple window with one QPushButton. When I press the button, it will start "ls" command and when it will be finished (termination signal caught) it writes "Process finished" message. However when I uncomment:

```
dolfin::Mesh mesh;
```

QProcess'es signal "finished()" is never emits, and process "ls" becomes zombie:

```
vitek@greyfox:~$ ps aux | grep "\[ls"
vitek    15357  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    11:46   0:00 [ls] <defunct>
vitek    15371  0.0  0.0   5620   836 pts/1    S+   11:47   0:00 grep --color=auto \[ls
```

So, I think dolfin::Mesh or library libdolfin.so somehow steals that termination signal or blocks it. 
dolfin::Mesh class source code is here https://github.com/FEniCS/dolfin/blob/master/dolfin/mesh/Mesh.cpp
How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried to get errorString() and also the stdout/err of the process? Can you use the `man 3 system` for a quick test to see if it is Qt related?

Comment: errorString() shows nothing, stdout/err of the process is list of files and dirs. Dont understand about `man 3 system`.

Comment: That means `ls` ran fine, at least to a certain extent. Well, read `man 3 system` and use that after the Dolfin mesh to see if you encounter the same issue. I would personally pin down whether it really is a QProcess issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorrow, currently I'm off from work computer.

Comment: Changed to http://pastebin.com/zjYbPyPK, output shows that system() call works as usual. We decided to exclude dolfin lib from out application and use VTK instead of it. But this question stays opened.

Comment: Have you tried without the connect line with QProcess?